# Extract the matched pattern (Numbers +Name) in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have used below mentioned pattern to Search and extract the string form big string.
example input string like

```
loadStringCombo('1',10,1,10,MaxCallApprComboBxId,quatstyle='width:50px;'quat)
```

Expected Output

```
(10,1,10,MaxCallApprComboBxId,)
```

But by this way i am getting only combobox1 as output.

```
while ( my $st = $str =~ /[0-9]+[\,][0-9]+[\,][0-9]+[\,][0-9a-zA-Z]+[\,]/g ) {
    my $str3 = "combobox" . $st;
    push @arry1, $str3 . "\n";
    print @arry1, "\n";
    open FILE, ">test.txt" or die $!;
    print FILE @arry1, "\n";
}
```

Please guide me to extract the value 10,1,10,MaxCallApprComboBxId,.

Comment: extract from????????????

Comment: -1 because this is perl and I can't read it. (jke :)

Comment: Please edit your question to add an example input (wider than `10,1,10,MaxCallApprComboBxId,`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
while ( my $st = $str =~ /[0-9]+[\,][0-9]+[\,][0-9]+[\,][0-9a-zA-Z]+[\,]/g ) {
```

by:

```
while ( my ($st) = $str =~ /(\d+,\d+,\d+,[0-9a-zA-Z]+,)/g ) {
```

whole loop:

```
while ($str =~ /(\d+,\d+,\d+,[0-9a-zA-Z]+,)/g ) {
    push @arry1, "combobox$1";
}
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper\@arry1;
open my $FILE, '>', 'test.txt' or die $!;
print $FILE "@arry1";
```

Comment: Thanks!But this is giving same result checkbox1

Comment: @RasikJesadiya: Soory, i've made a typo, see my edit.

Comment: @RasikJesadiya but there isn't a substring checkbox1 in your input

Comment: Hi M42, One step ahead by edited code but it goes to infinite loop with output combobox10,1,10,MaxCallApprComboBxId,